# VBPieChart - removeFromSuperView not working (hide chart)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, show-hide

I'm using [VBPieChart](http://github.com/sakrist/VBPieChart), in Objective C language. I'm showing the chart on `valueChange` of a segmented control, like :

```
- (IBAction)segmentControlAction:(UISegmentedControl *)sender
    {
    switch ([sender selectedSegmentIndex])
    {
        case 0:

            [self showPieChart:NO];
            _tableViewForCount.hidden = NO;
            [_tableViewForCount reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];

            break;
        case 1:

            _tableViewForCount.hidden = YES;

            [self showPieChart:YES];

            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"None");
            break;
    }
}
```

and the `showPieChart` method goes like :

```
- (void) showPieChart:(Boolean)visible
{
    VBPieChart *chart = [[VBPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
    chart.center = self.view.center;

    // Setup some options:
    [chart setHoleRadiusPrecent:0.3]; /* hole inside of chart */

    // Prepare your data
    NSMutableArray *chartValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:                             @{@"name":@"Apples", @"value":@50, @"color":[UIColor redColor]},
                             @{@"name":@"Pears", @"value":@20, @"color":[UIColor blueColor]},
                             @{@"name":@"Oranges", @"value":@40, @"color":[UIColor orangeColor]},
                             @{@"name":@"Bananas", @"value":@70, @"color":[UIColor purpleColor]}, nil
                             ];


    if (visible)
    {
        chart.center = self.view.center;
        // Present pie chart with animation
        [chart setChartValues:chartValues animation:YES duration:0.4 options:VBPieChartAnimationFan];
        [self.view addSubview:chart];
    }
    else
    {
        // remove chart
        [chart removeFromSuperView];
    }
}
```

Since `VBPieChart` is just a custom subclass of UIView, this should work. But i'm not getting any success.

I've also tried `[chart setHidden:YES];` as well as `[chart setAlpha:0.0];` , but still no luck.

Any help would is appreciated. I just want to hide/remove the chart when user switched back to segment index 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBPieChart *chart create this object on the .h file then

```
- (void) showPieChart:(Boolean)visible
{
    if(chart == nil)
    {
        chart = [[VBPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
        [self.view addSubview:chart];
    }
    chart.center = self.view.center;

    // Setup some options:
    [chart setHoleRadiusPrecent:0.3]; /* hole inside of chart */

    // Prepare your data
    NSMutableArray *chartValues = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:                             @{@"name":@"Apples", @"value":@50, @"color":[UIColor redColor]},
                             @{@"name":@"Pears", @"value":@20, @"color":[UIColor blueColor]},
                             @{@"name":@"Oranges", @"value":@40, @"color":[UIColor orangeColor]},
                             @{@"name":@"Bananas", @"value":@70, @"color":[UIColor purpleColor]}, nil
                             ];


    if (visible)
    {
        chart.center = self.view.center;
        // Present pie chart with animation
        [chart setChartValues:chartValues animation:YES duration:0.4 options:VBPieChartAnimationFan];
        chart.alpa = 1.0
    }
    else
    {
        // remove chart
        chart.alpa = 0.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create variable as below.

```
 static  VBPieChart *chart = nil
 if(!chart)
  chart  = [[VBPieChart alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 250, 250)];
    }
   if (visible)
    {
        chart.hidden = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        // hide chart
        chart.hidden = YES;
    }
```